# Complement of a Conic is Affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

I've been studying quasi-projective varieties, and on the Wikipedia page it says the complement of a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is affine, but it does not justify it or say what it is isomorphic to (or give a citation). I'm trying to figure out how that's true.

I know that to be affine it must be isomorphic to a Zariski-closed set, but what is the complement of a conic isomorphic to?

Comment: Do you know that complement of a hyperplane in projective space is affine? Do you know Veronese embedding?

Comment: @Mohan yes I'm familiar with the veronese embedding

Comment: If you embed $\mathbb{P}^2$ by degree 2 Veronese (in 5-space), the conic is the intersection  of a hyperplane with the image of the plane and thus the complement is affine.

Comment: @ABitTooCurious The degree 2 Veronese embeds the plane as a closed subset  $X$ of  five space. The conic then is $H\cap X$ where $H$ is a hyperplane in five space. So, $X-X\cap H=X\cap (\mathbb{P}^5-H)= X\cap \mathbb{A}^5$. So, it is identified as a closed subset of affine five space, which is the definition of affine.

Comment: @ABitTooCurious $X$ is the image of the plane under the Veronese map.

Comment: Because it's isomorphic as a Stein surface to the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{RP}^2$, which is affine because it's the algebraic quotient of the affine conic by $\mathbb{Z}/2$.